# Create column that groups a sequence of consecutive dates with ID in R

Tags: r, sequence

I have been trying to find a solution to this and am unsure if it would require multiple steps using dplyr and/or creating some kind of function. Essentially, I want to create an "event" column with variables that link a sequence/repeat dates and ID together and indicate the event order.

before:

```
event date        id         
2020-12-25        111       
2020-12-26        111        
2020-12-27        111        
2020-12-30        222        
2020-12-30        222        
2021-01-30        333        
2021-01-31        333        
2021-05-25        222        
2021-05-26        222  
2021-07-08        222
2021-07-09        222
```

after:

```
event date        id         event
2020-12-25        111        1
2020-12-26        111        1
2020-12-27        111        1
2020-12-30        222        1
2020-12-30        222        1
2021-01-30        333        1
2021-01-31        333        1
2021-05-25        222        2
2021-05-26        222        2
2021-07-08        222        3
2021-07-09        222        3
```

The process to assign event values is essentially if the id is linked to a sequence of dates that are consecutive, then this can be grouped into an event. If the id is linked to multiple consecutive dates/individual dates, then that is a new and separate event associated with that id.

edit: added more data points to provide more info

Comment: Yes, just the same without the event column

Comment: Thank you for providing the desire output. What does the original data look like? Just the same without the `event` column? Also, could you clarify the process to assign `event` values? Is it because `id==333` came between the two groups of `222`?

Comment: I tried to clarify in the original post.

Comment: Why is 2020-12-30 assigned even 1 yet it is 3 days from the previous date? How do you define consecutive?

Comment: 2020-12-30 is associated with a different id so that is a new event (1) for that id.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of `diff` and `cumsum` -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(event_date = as.Date(event_date)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(event = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(event_date) > 1))) %>%
  ungroup

df

#  event_date    id event
#  <date>     <int> <int>
#1 2020-12-25   111     1
#2 2020-12-26   111     1
#3 2020-12-27   111     1
#4 2020-12-30   222     1
#5 2020-12-30   222     1
#6 2021-01-30   333     1
#7 2021-01-31   333     1
#8 2021-05-25   222     2
#9 2021-05-26   222     2
```

For each `id`, `event` value is incremented when the difference between consecutive dates is greater than 1.

Comment: this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

We can capitalize on `data.table::rleid` for this.

(I converted your `event_date` to a `Date`-class before running these.)

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, r1 := rleid(id, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(event_date) > 1)))
  ][, event2 := match(r1, unique(r1)), by = id
  ][, r1 := NULL ]
#    event_date  id event event2
# 1: 2020-12-25 111     1      1
# 2: 2020-12-26 111     1      1
# 3: 2020-12-27 111     1      1
# 4: 2020-12-30 222     1      1
# 5: 2020-12-30 222     1      1
# 6: 2021-01-30 333     1      1
# 7: 2021-01-31 333     1      1
# 8: 2021-05-25 222     2      2
# 9: 2021-05-26 222     2      2
```

---

For non-`data.table` applications where you don't have it installed, you can use

```r
my_rleid <- function(...) {
  r <- rle(do.call(paste, c(list(...), sep = "_")))$lengths
  rep(seq_along(r), times = r)
}
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(r1 = my_rleid(id, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(event_date) > 1)))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(event2 = match(r1, unique(r1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-r1)
```

### base R

```r
r1 <- my_rleid(dat$id, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(dat$event_date) > 1)))
dat$event2 <- ave(r1, dat$id, FUN = function(z) match(z, unique(z)))
dat$r1 <- NULL
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(event_date = structure(c(18621, 18622, 18623, 18626, 18626, 18657, 18658, 18772, 18773), class = "Date"), id = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 222L, 222L, 333L, 333L, 222L, 222L), event = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: Can you be less vague? It doesn't work *how*? Are you getting an error? Does it not count something correctly? Since it works with the sample data you provided (even the updated data, though I haven't edited my question to reflect that *it also works*), it is incredibly helpful if you update your sample data to include a situation where this code does not work as intended.

Comment: @kvukki your comment is very difficult for others to understand.  Imagine you are answering the question that matches the expected output and you get a comment like `this doesn't work`.